# Show half of the div after click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've this div and it shows about five records. what I want is it show first three records on page load and rest all records  (all together) after i click the div.

Let me tell where I'm stuck.

This is the **MAIN** div

```
<div id="candidateDetails{CNDID}" style="height:80px; z-index:1; overflow:auto;  display: block; position: relative;">
```

and in this div I've multiple div's which show records

as you can see here

```js
 <div>' +
                        '     <input type="checkbox" name="CandidateProcessed" id="candidateChecked{CNDID}"> ' +
                        '     <img  style="width: 5%; " src="data:image/png;base64,{ProfileImage}"> {FirstName}' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div>{PassportNumber} Flight #: {FlightNumber}</div>' +
                         '<div style="">' +
                                '<div >Visa : {VisaNumber}</div>' +
                                '<div >Status : {Status}</div>' +
                                '<div >Org. : {Organization}</div>' +
                                '<div >Job : {Job}</div>' +
                                '<div >Vendor : {Vendor_name}</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>
```

I want it to show me  on page load first two div's and when I click that dive it should load rest of the div's and expand

my Current situation looks like this

http://prntscr.com/88mwqs

here is my javaScript file

```
Ext.define('TransGuard.view.agent.PlannedArrival', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',

    xtype: 'plannedArrival',
    requires: [
        'Ext.Anim',
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.data.Store',
        'Ext.List',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Rest',
        'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
        'Ext.plugin.ListPaging'
    ],
    config: {
        itemId: 'plannedArrivalId',
        scrollable: true,
        height: Ext.getBody().getHeight() - 150,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'hbox',
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'searchfield',
                    margin: '0 10 0 10'
                },
                scrollable: true,
                items: [
                    {
                        placeHolder: 'Name',
                        name: 'query'
                    },
                    {
                        placeHolder: 'Passport Number',
                        name: 'querys'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                height: Ext.getBody().getHeight(),//-315,
                id: 'pACandidatesList',
                cls: 'allCandidates',
                store: 'Users',
                itemHeight: 110,
                overflow: 'hidden',
                scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,
                plugins: [
                    {
                        xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
                        autoPaging: true,
                        loadMoreText: 'Loading...',
                        noMoreRecordsText: 'No More Records'
                    }
                ],

                itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                    '<a href="#" id="candidateDetails{CNDID}" class="show_hide">Show/hide</a><br />' +
                        '<div class="slidingDiv" id="candidateDetailsInner{CNDID}">' +

                            'Fill this space with really interesting content. <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a>' +
                        '</div>'
                    '<div id="candidateDetails{CNDID}" style="height:80px;">' +
                    '<div>' +
                    '     <input type="checkbox" name="CandidateProcessed" id="candidateChecked{CNDID}"> ' +
                    '     <img  style="width: 5%; " src="data:image/png;base64,{ProfileImage}"> {FirstName}' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div>{PassportNumber} Flight #: {FlightNumber}</div>' +
                    '<div style=" ">' +
                    '<div >Visa : {VisaNumber}</div>' +
                    '<div >Status : {Status}</div>' +
                    '<div >Org. : {Organization}</div>' +
                    '<div >Job : {Job}</div>' +
                    '<div >Vendor : {Vendor_name}</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>',
                    {
                        getMyValue: function (values) {
                            console.log(values)
                        }
                    }
                ),
                emptyText: 'No records available'
            }, { xtype: 'label', margin: '25 0 0 0', color: '#e7a721', html: 'Arrival Process: New arrival' },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                cls: 'newArival',
                width: Ext.getBody().getWidth() - 100,
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    cls: 'pArrivedRadioBtn',
                    xclass: 'Ext.field.Select',
                    labelWidth: '70%'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        name: 'arrivalStatus',
                        value: '1',
                        id: 'pArrivedRadioBtn',
                        label: 'Arrived',
                        checked: true,
                        labelCls: 'plannedArrived'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'arrivalStatus',
                        value: '0',
                        label: 'Not Arrived',
                        labelCls: 'plannedArrived'
                    }
                ]
            }, { xtype: 'label', html: 'Client Accomudation' },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                width: Ext.getBody().getWidth() - 100,
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    cls: 'pArrivedRadioBtn',
                    xclass: 'Ext.field.Select',
                    labelWidth: '70%',
                    labelCls: 'plannedArrived'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        name: 'accomodation',
                        id: 'pClientAccomodation',
                        value: '1',
                        label: 'Yes',
                        checked: true
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'accomodation',
                        value: '0',
                        label: 'No'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: 'hbox',
                defaults: {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    margin: '10 0 10 10'
                },
                items: [
                    { xtype: 'spacer' },
                    {
                        text: 'Cancel',
                        name: 'PACancelBtn'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Process',
                        name: 'PAProcessBtn'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: What is your javascript code? In order to hide the content you could use `overflow:hidden` and in order to show it you could put the `height` to `auto`.

Comment: I tried that still thats not working, I'm now trying to achieve that with '<ul>'

Answer (score 0):

Put your div in a wrapper, then a wrapper for the first two div with an id for exemple `part1`; and a second wrapper for the others div with id `part2`.

As so :

```
<div class="General-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper" id="part1">
      //the two div
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper" id="part2">
       //the rest of the div
   </div>
</div>
```

And in your JQuery script :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#part1').show();
   $('#part2').hide();

//then on click event 
   $( "yourdiv" ).click(function() {
       $('#part2').show();
});
```

Comment: This one looks promising let me try it

Comment: forgot the '$' before two arguments in the JS. Now it's okay

Comment: tried this one too but not working same problem as before

Comment: @KhawajaAtteeq did you put your div `height` in `auto` ? because if you don't it won't work

Comment: It works fine for single record as Mine data is coming from database and its a sort of loop and there could be over thousands of records I believe its because of that or so

Comment: Each data have a unique Id. No matter the numbers you can still call them. Or give the data generated from database a class and call all the data with this class in the jQuery script.

Comment: Yes I do know that and that is why I was surprised over that too because every one has a unique id still the issue, it does not show any java script error even in the console

Comment: I can help you only if you give me more information. Can you give me your script and your css ? Do it with js fiddle its better

Comment: But as I said before if you generate each data with the same class (data for exemple) and put in your css .data {padding: 10px; width: auto; height: auto;} it should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing any javascript code, which makes it hard to see how you're trying to tackle this problem.

Here is a very simple jQuery solution to your problem that works by limiting the height and setting a `overflow:hidden`. You show the div by putting height back to `auto`.

http://jsfiddle.net/e61004xz/

Comment: Maybe if you give us your full code we can see the issue, because as you can see the code I gave you works.

Comment: I'm fetching data from an an API actually, and yes I'm going to update the code right away

Comment: I don't see any event handlers that change the height of the div when it's clicked, this is only code to load in the content and not relevant to the question.